# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ReactSharedInternals.hasOwnProperty')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, package.json

I am building my first React Native app on my own. While I was trying to set up navigation in my RN app, I ran into several module errors regarding importing RN libraries. I managed to solve them. However, now I am faced with a very bizarre red screen error that I (to be frank), have no idea where to even begin debugging.

The error looks like [this.](https://gyazo.com/e187ef4fab9b3fc34e20abedec8c12a3)

I have no idea what this means, and I inspected the files mentioned on the error screen, but I couldn't make sense of it. They seem to be very low-level files that I shouldn't tinker with.

I've `npm i <library-here>` as well as `react-native link <library-here>` and that did not resolve the problem. I have destroyed and re-installed npm and that also did not work. I also restarted my frontend server but it appears to be something inherent to my project setup.

I have a feeling this is related to my `package.json`s, as I had to change my `react-navigation` versions in both my `src` (my React Native folder that holds frontend files) to `2.14.0`. I also changed the `package.json` in my project root so `react-navigation` was using the most recent, stable version: `^4.0.10`.

Here is my `src/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "src",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo-image-picker": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.19",
    "react-navigation": "2.14.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Here is my `package.json` in my project root that I changed the `react-navigation`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.19",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10"
  }
}
```

In case it is needed, this is my `AppNavigator.js`, which I call in my `App.js`:

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { Platform } from "react-native";
// Importing my screens here.
import LoginCreateAccountScreen from "../screens/LoginCreateAccountScreen";
import CreateAccountScreen from "../screens/CreateAccountScreen";
import LoginScreen from "../screens/LoginScreen";
import SplashScreen from "../screens/SplashScreen";

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SplashScreen: {screen: SplashScreen},
  LoginCreateAccountScreen: {screen: LoginCreateAccountScreen},
  LoginScreen: {screen: LoginScreen},
  CreateAccountScreen: {screen: CreateAccountScreen},
});

export default createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            // You could add another route here for authentication.
            // Read more at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html
            SplashScreen: SplashScreen,
            LoginCreateAccountScreen: LoginCreateAccountScreen,
            LoginScreen: LoginScreen,
            CreateAccountScreen: CreateAccountScreen
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen' // Entry
        }
    )
);
```

My `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <AppNavigator />;
    }
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried deleting package.lock.json and then running npm i?

Comment: I just did, and it didn't resolve the problem. I got a new error (edited in original post).

Comment: please try deleting node_modules as well as package.lock.json one more time and try npm i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can cause because the `react` version doesn't match the `react-native` version.

Try to update it to `react@16.0.0-alpha.12` like this:

```
npm install react@16.0.0-alpha.12
```

Or change `react@16.0.0-alpha.6` in your `package.json` to `react@16.0.0-alpha.12` and run `npm install`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not resolve my problem. It successfully upgraded my `react` to `^16.0.0-alpha.12` I get a new error screen: https://gyazo.com/a152581167008bce9c53c93949c140e8

Comment: @McFloofenbork sorry can you try to delete node_modules folder and run npm install again? It can be a conflict in the new and old versions of react.

Comment: I just tried that, and it did not resolve the issue, either. I've upgraded my `react to 16.4.1`, and am back to square 1: https://gyazo.com/e187ef4fab9b3fc34e20abedec8c12a3

Comment: Yes, a new error. I was getting a very bizarre https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54302725/react-createcontext-is-not-a-function-but-i-am-not-using-it error after I followed your instructions. I tried upgrading per the responses on that post and got a new error.

Comment: Try the solution from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53388478/getting-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-0-reactnavigation-stacknaviga

Comment: Maybe you already have solve the problem, because this new error doesn't look similar to your first error and you didn't see this problem because of your first error.

Comment: Actually, I've been alternating back and forth between this "new" error and other new errors multiple times. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: React Native is very tricky because of very rapid developing and updating it gets too complicated and causes a lot of package related errors. I'm glad I helped you. Good luck with that))